# PageRequest above page 1 returning the same result

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following get function which should return trips inside of a page with optional specifications.

```
@GetMapping("/trip")
    Page<Trip> all(@SearchSpec Specification<Trip> specs,
                   @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
                   @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1000") int pageSize) {
        //return repository.findAll(Specification.where(specs));
        return repository.findAll(Specification.where(specs), PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("searchKey").ascending()));
    }
```

Now when I make the following request to my API:
`http://localhost:8080/trip?page=0&pageSize=2&search=departureAirport:'AMS'`

I get back 2 records(trips) from my API which is correct. When I change the request to:
`http://localhost:8080/trip?page=1&pageSize=2&search=departureAirport:'AMS'`

So to the next page, I get the next 2 records(trips) from my API which is also correct, but as soon as I want to go to page 2 the API returns the same records as on page 1. So every page above page 1 returns the same records.

I am able to increase the pageSize and when I do this the API returns more records, but again every page above 1 returns the same. So only the data on page 0 and 1 is different.

I tried removing the Specification and the sorting but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is the sorting-parameter (`searchKey`) unique for every row?

Comment: Yes it is. it is a String value that is also used as the primary key in the database.

Comment: What do the responses to the calls mention about the requested page? (In the response, at least as JSON, the current page number and an offset are mentioned) Just tried to reproduce your problem, but it works as expected: page 0 requests with an offset of 0, page 1 with 1000, page 2 with 2000 and so on.

Comment: The offset and number of Elements are right. In this case I did page=2&pageSize=2 and this returned the following page overhead:

"pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "unsorted": false,
            "sorted": true,
            "empty": false
        },
        "offset": 4,
        "pageNumber": 2,
        "pageSize": 2,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 26091,
    "totalElements": 52182,
    "last": false,
    "size": 2,
    "number": 2,
    "numberOfElements": 2,

But it still sends the data from page 1

Comment: Could the problem be that I am using a Sqlite database instead of h2?

Comment: Okay, seems like hibernate doesn't support sqlite out of the box. (Don't know, what has to be implemented on its own  regarding Dialect etc. to reproduce). But maybe you could activate sql-logging (in `application.properties`: `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`, `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`) to see what SQL is performed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using my own paging algorithm since the problem was probably related to Sqlite and I didn't want to change my database client. I ended up using the following code in my Get request:

```
List<Trip> trips = repository.findAll(Specification.where(specs));
if (sort.equals("desc")) trips.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
if(page > 0) {
    if ( page == 1) {
        trips = trips.subList(0, pageSize);
    } else {
        trips = trips.subList(((page - 1) * pageSize), page * pageSize);
    }
}
return trips;
```